# Составить программу, которая запрашивает два целых числа для нахождения их суммы. Вывести на экран числа, сумма которых оказалась наименьшей

Tags: циклы, pascal

При выполнении программы, он не требует вводить заново цифры для суммы 
Вначале вводить две цифры и потом не понятно как выполняется программа

```
Var a,b,N, max, next, k: integer;Begin
      Write('Введите количество чисел'); Readln(n);
       write('Введите число a: '); read(a);
       write('Введите число b: '); read(b); 
      Write('Сумма чисел: ',a+b); Readln(max);
      k:=1;
      repeat
        write('Введите число a: ',a); Readln(next);
        write('Введите число b: ',b); Readln(next);
        K:=k+1;
        If next>max then max:=next
      Until k=n;
      Writeln(max);
      Readln
    End.
```

Comment: Непонятно в чем вопрос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всегда форматируйте код, так проще разобраться и найти ошибку.

```
program test;

var
  a, b, N, max, Next, k: integer;
begin
  write('Введите количество чисел');
  readln(n);

  write('Введите число a: ');
  read(a);

  write('Введите число b: ');
  read(b);

  write('Сумма чисел: ', a + b);

  readln(max);

  k := 1;
  repeat
    write('Введите число a: ', a);
    readln(Next);

    write('Введите число b: ', b);
    readln(Next);

    K := k + 1;
    if Next > max then
      max := Next
  until k = n;

  writeln(max);

  readln;
end.
```

Проблема после вывода суммы чисел `writeln('Сумма чисел: ', a + b);`. По коду воспринимается, что это заголовок ко вводу, но это просто вывод. Поэтому ввод `max` остается без комментария и кажется, что программа зависла.

Думаю в этом месте вместо `readln(max);` должно быть `max := a + b`.